# How long can you store liquid tomato food after mixing?

Tags: fertilizer

I've bought a bottle of concentrated tomato feed. The mix ratio is 25ml concentrate to 4L

I was hoping to mix a large amount in a tank and connect it to a gravity fed dripper irrigation system.

I can't work out if doing so will result in the fertilizer spoiling or encouraging mould / mildew growth in my tank.

**Summary: What is the shelf life of diluted plant feed**

Comment: If your system is sterile, the diluted feed should last indefinitely. But it will be a free lunch for any microorganisms that can get in there (e.g. from air circulation), especially if the system is not lightproof.

Comment: Whenever I've left a fertilizer/water solution it turns cloudy in a day or so. I think I'm seeing a practical demonstration of what @alephzero mentions. If you can't keep the solution sterile, it's big container of wet food for any opportunistic organism.